# Dropdown additional white space inside iframe in Chrome

Tags: css

I can see some additional white space around the dropdown in iframe.

Testing env:

- Chrome Version 78.0.3904.87 (I recently updated)
- Windows 10
- Happens inside iframe only

What is the reason behind it and how this can be fixed ?

```css
body{
background: black;
}
```

```html
<select>
      <option>Samsung Phone</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Nokia</option>
      <option>LG</option>
</select>
```

Here is how it looks
[image]

Comment: I'm using the exact same version of Chrome on Windows 10. I do not see the issue from your snippet.

Comment: Same here. No repro

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when it's inside an iframe, Chrome version 78.0.3904.108, and Scale and layout by default set to 125% (Recommended) (right mouse click on Desktop, choose Display Settings).

If I set Scale and layout back to 100%, the select dropdown is normal.  I suspect it's a latest Chrome's bug.

Thanks.